# How to change spring security from ldap to ldap starttls

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap, spring-ldap

How to change spring security  from ldap to ldap starttls.

I am writing a project in Springs using Spring Security and LDAP.  I had everything working great and then the admin changed it to ldap with starttls.  Can someone please show me how to update my xml file to get my project working again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" >

    <http
        auto-config="true"
        use-expressions="true" >

        <intercept-url
            access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER_INQUIRY')"
            pattern="/requests/**" />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager >

        <ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-base="ou=webusers"
            user-search-filter="(uid={0})" >

            <password-compare >

                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" >
                </password-encoder>
            </password-compare>
        </ldap-authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean
        id="passwordEncoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" >
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
        id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource" >

        <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://10.52.208.228:389/dc=xxxxx,dc=dev" />

        <beans:property
            name="userDn"
            value="cn=Manager,dc=xxxxx,dc=dev" />

        <beans:property
            name="password"
            value="secret" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
        id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider" >

        <beans:constructor-arg >

            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator" >

                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />

                <beans:property name="userDnPatterns" >

                    <beans:list >

                        <beans:value >

uid={0},ou=webusers

                        </beans:value>
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>

        <beans:constructor-arg >

            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator" >

                <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />

                <beans:constructor-arg value="ou=groups" />

                <beans:property
                    name="groupRoleAttribute"
                    value="ou" />
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <ldap-server url="ldap://10.52.208.228:389/dc=xxxxx,dc=dev" />

    <beans:bean
        id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >

        <beans:property
            name="location"
            value="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean
        id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >

        <beans:property
            name="driverClassName"
            value="${database.driver}" />

        <beans:property
            name="url"
            value="${database.url}" />

        <beans:property
            name="username"
            value="${database.user}" />

        <beans:property
            name="password"
            value="${database.password}" />

        <beans:property
            name="initialSize"
            value="5" />

        <beans:property
            name="maxActive"
            value="10" />
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: TLS is initiated on a clear text connection by the use of the StartTLS extended operation. The LDAP client should still be able to use the clear text connection. Or did you mean to say that the directory server administrator is now causing connections to be closed if the first request made on the connection is not StartTLS?

Comment: You may need to import the ldap server certificate to the app server's keystore.

Answer (score 2):

You need to supply a DirContextAuthenticationStrategy implementation to the ContextSource in the configuration.

See:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/reference/html/configuration.html